# React native flex box not using all available space

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

I have a layout that I want to make full screen. This is how it looks right now: [image]

What I want is for the layout to take up all the space on the screen (so the submit button should be way down at the bottom). I'm trying to use `{flex: 1}` but it's not working. Here's the code:

```
'use strict';

const React = require('react-native');
const {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  BackAndroid,
  TextInput,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  ScrollView
} = React;

const ActionButton = require('./action-button');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  handleBackButtonPress () {
    if (this.props.navigator) {
      this.props.navigator.pop();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  },

  componentWillMount () {
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonPress);
  },

  componentWillUnmount () {
    BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonPress);
  },

  onInputFocus (refName) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let scrollResponder = this.refs.scrollView.getScrollResponder();
      scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
        React.findNodeHandle(this.refs[refName]),
        0,
        true
      );
    }, 50);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <ScrollView ref='scrollView' style={styles.scroller}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text>New Post</Text>

              <View style={styles.actions}>
                <ActionButton handler={this.handleBackButtonPress} icon={'fontawesome|close'}
                  size={15} width={15} height={15} />
              </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <TextInput underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
              placeholder={'Who\'s your professor?'}
              ref='professor'
              onFocus={this.onInputFocus.bind(this, 'professor')}
              style={styles.professor}
              />

            <TextInput multiline={true}
              underlineColorAndroid={'white'}
              placeholder={'What do you think?'}
              ref='post'
              onFocus={this.onInputFocus.bind(this, 'post')}
              style={styles.post}
              />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.footer}>
            <TouchableNativeFeedback
              background={TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()}>

              <View style={{width: 50, height: 25, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
                <Text>Submit</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableNativeFeedback>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scroller: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 5,
  },
  post: {
    flex: 3
  },
  professor: {
    flex: 1
  },
  actions: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  content: {
    flex: 4
  },
  footer: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

From what I can see, I'm setting the flex property all the way down the view hierarchy but that still isn't doing anything (at the top level is a Navigator with {flex: 1} as well). Any suggestions?

Comment: are you containing this view in another container?

Answer (score 21):

What you want is the `contentContainerStyle` prop of the `ScrollView` component. If you replace :

```
<ScrollView ref='scrollView' style={styles.scroller}>
```

with :

```
<ScrollView ref='scrollView' contentContainerStyle={styles.scroller}>
```

That will fix your problem.

As stated [in the doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) :

> These styles will be applied to the scroll view content container which wraps all of the child views.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This fixed my problem instantly. However, it made the ScrollView stop scrolling when the content goes past the bottom of the view, so it basically turned it into a <View /> by changing `style` to `contentContainerStyle`. I tried both at the same time and that also didn't work as intended.

Comment: Same. This does not work with RN 0.48/Expo 21.0. Edit, this seemed to work: `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}`.

Comment: Using `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}` also did the trick for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If the colors are accurate in the screenshot, your scrollview is taking up all the vertical space already but the container is not (container background color is white). This is illustrating how scrollviews work. They act as containers where flex can't really grow the children to fit the vertical space as it is potentially infinite. Instead the children are rendered at their natural height. http://devdocs.io/react_native/scrollview

try instead using a view that takes up the entire screen height.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  ... components here ...
</View>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a flexDirection: 'row' property for the outermost container:

```
scroller: {
  flex:1,
  flexDirection: 'row'
}
```

I've set up a basic version of your app [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/gjBqgw). The rest of the code is pasted below for the full working example:

https://rnplay.org/apps/gjBqgw

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  BackAndroid,
  TextInput,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  ScrollView,
  AppRegistry,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
    return (
      <ScrollView ref='scrollView' style={styles.scroller}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text>New Post</Text>

              <View style={styles.actions}>
                <TouchableHighlight handler={this.handleBackButtonPress} icon={'fontawesome|close'}
                  size={15} width={15} height={15}>
                            <Text>Button Text</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.content}>
           <Text>Hello from content</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.footer}>
            <TouchableHighlight>

              <View style={{width: 50, height: 25, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
                <Text>Submit</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );

  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scroller: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 5,
  },
  post: {
    flex: 3
  },
  professor: {
    flex: 1
  },
  actions: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  header: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  content: {
    flex: 4
  },
  footer: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: why making flex-direction as row fix the problem? Doesn't it make the main axis left-right? And doing flex: 1 take the whole available space in horizontal direction? @nader-dabit

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it only made the content disappear.